# Using the win32 API in vs code

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, winapi, character-encoding, linker

I've started the process in bringing my program ideas to life. My problem is i cannot seem to get the api to work and run.

I am using visual studio code and the mingw x64 compiler.

i am simply running the sample code the from Microsoft on how to build a direct2d program,

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-direct2d-program)

and the base window class from managing application state,

[reference 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/managing-application-state-)

only difference is that i got lazy and copy and pasted the basewidow class instead of including it like they did with basewin.h

The Problem:

when i run the sample code i get this error,

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\uub17\AppData\Local\Temp\ccti919g.o:myprogram.cpp:(.text$_Z17D2D1CreateFactory17D2D1_FACTORY_TYPERK5_GUIDPPv[_Z17D2D1CreateFactory17D2D1_FACTORY_TYPERK5_GUIDPPv]+0x2b): undefined reference to `D2D1CreateFactory'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
C:/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

i did some searching and found out that the api is divided into Ansi and Unicode, so i tried out the Unicode version of the api entry point "winMain" instead of "wwinMain" and changed "pwstr" to "pstr", when i run it i then get this output in the terminal,

```
In instantiation of 'BOOL BaseWindow<DERIVED_TYPE>::Create(PCWSTR, DWORD, DWORD, int, int, int, int, HWND, HMENU) [with DERIVED_TYPE = MainWindow; BOOL = int; PCWSTR = const wchar_t*; DWORD = long unsigned int; HWND = HWND__*; HMENU = HMENU__*]':
myprogram.cpp:202:20:   required from here
myprogram.cpp:54:37: error: cannot convert 'PCWSTR' {aka 'const wchar_t*'} to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'} in assignment
   54 |         wc.lpszClassName = ClassName();
      |                            ~~~~~~~~~^~
      |                                     |
      |                                     PCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}
myprogram.cpp:59:33: error: cannot convert 'PCWSTR' {aka 'const wchar_t*'} to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'}
   59 |             dwExStyle, ClassName(), lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~^~
      |                                 |
      |                                 PCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/windows.h:72,
                 from myprogram.cpp:1:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/winuser.h:2203:65: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'HWND__* CreateWindowExA(DWORD, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, DWORD, int, int, int, int, HWND, HMENU, HINSTANCE, LPVOID)'
 2203 |   WINUSERAPI HWND WINAPI CreateWindowExA(DWORD dwExStyle,LPCSTR lpClassName,LPCSTR lpWindowName,DWORD dwStyle,int X,int Y,int nWidth,int nHeight,HWND hWndParent,HMENU hMenu,HINSTANCE hInstance,LPVOID lpParam);
```

I did more searching and saw somewhere that my mingw crt compiler doesnt support unicode or wide characters or somethind and must use WinMain, so i kept WinMain as the entry point and defined UNICODE and _UNICODE which is already defined in the cpp properties json folder, and i get this in the terminal

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\uub17\AppData\Local\Temp\ccT85reo.o:myprogram.cpp:(.text$_Z17D2D1CreateFactory17D2D1_FACTORY_TYPERK5_GUIDPPv[_Z17D2D1CreateFactory17D2D1_FACTORY_TYPERK5_GUIDPPv]+0x2b): undefined reference to `D2D1CreateFactory'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I dont know much but i went as far as changing everything that deals with strings to either ansi and unicode versions to remove the need for conversion but generally i get the same result.

I do not understand how code from the microsoft site can fail and how a compiler that is made for win32 doesnt support what the os supports.

i literally cant run sample code lol, please educate me

generally everything i tried was changing to the versions of the functions that are ansi, trying to use Unicode anyway although appaerently it is incompattible with my compiler by using different macros and defines provided by microsoft, and checking the vscode json and build settings, which are

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

```
tasks.json

{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],

            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }



    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe try a basic `MessageBox` hello world program before jumping into Direct2d...

Comment: Why don't you try Visual Studio Community Edition instead of VSCore+MinGW? It's free, and you won't deal with MinGW problems - I simply don't use it anymore but for extremely basic stuff, it's too annoying: the last version I had (shipped with Qt 6.2.3) don't even allow to compile debug executables out-of-the box! You may also lacks a proper WinSDK and/or DirectX SDK...

Comment: *"a compiler that is made for win32 doesnt support what the os supports"* - GCC isn't made for Windows programming. MinGW is an attempt at retrofitting Windows support, but the support is spotty, with manually adjusted SDK header files, and custom import libraries. Usually ancient, too. Especially when using COM from C++ compiler internals suddenly become part of the public interface. I wouldn't be using GCC here. This is best done using MSVC or Clang. Then again, I wouldn't be using VS Code anyway. By the time you want to debug your program you'd wish you were using Visual Studio instead.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks that information helped alot and yeeeeeaaahh, "Then again, I wouldn't be using VS Code anyway. By the time you want to debug your program you'd wish you were using Visual Studio instead", I'm noticing that pretty quick. Are there any other compilers i should know about or stay away from, lol i really dont wanna go through this again

Comment: @Wisblade just downloaded it

Comment: @IInspectable VSCode can be a nice tool, but when you use it for what it's best for (IMHO): controlling a *nix/embedded remote machine from Windows with a not-so-bad interface and various interconnected tools... Or as a general-purpose text editor. For me, in IDE mode, it's a good alternative to Eclipse (or to a bare SSH terminal...), because Eclipse is f*cking HUGE and slow as a painful death. But in no way it can be compared to Visual Studio for Windows development... Even QtCreator is way below VS, and QtC is already more advanced than VSCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `D2D1CreateFactory` can't be found because you aren't linking `D2d1.lib` as specified in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-d2d1createfactory.
Add `-ld2d1` argument to command line. Maybe you need to use also `-L` directive to specify directory.

For MSVC compiler `pragma` directive can be used (which probably doesn't work for `mingw`).

```
#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1")
```

**EDITED**

Added `"-ld2d1",` just before `"-o",`.

```
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-ld2d1",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
```

Comment: Sek thanks  man, yea i had the pragma comment in there but i am using mingw. I added the arguments to the command line and got the following results below. I dont have much knowledge when it comes to using the terminal, I looked up the command line arguments for vs code but couldnt find the ones you've shown me here

Comment: - 1d21
+ - 1d21
+  ~
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At line:1 char:3
+ - 1d21
+   ~~~~
Unexpected token '1d21' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator

Comment: - L
+ - L
+  ~
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At line:1 char:3
+ - L
+   ~
Unexpected token 'L' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
+ - L 1d2d1
+  ~
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At line:1 char:3
+ - L 1d2d1
+   ~
Unexpected token 'L' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator

Comment: Don't try to type it from my answer, just copy it because it is `-ld2d1`. Put `"-ld2d1",` for example before `"-o",` (I'm assuming that you have d2d1 library).

Comment: Sek, you're the best, it worked